# How can I check the status of battle.net?

Tags: battle.net

I found myself unable to connect to battle.net (the gaming network as opposed to the battle.net website). In this case the problem was with battle.net service. In the future I would like to check if the issue is on my side or if the battle.net service is down.

I was using the battle.net login client.

Specifically, I was unable to log into the battle.net service. I am not interested in any of the game specific servers.

How can I check the status of battle.net?
Is there an official status of the battle.net service available somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer versions of the Battle.net desktop client display server maintenance alerts. These alerts seem to be for individual services (eg WoW, Starcraft 2) and ***might not be visible if the battle.net alert infrastructure itself is down***.

If you know of a reliable way of checking the status of Battle.net if the Battle.net alerts aren't working, please post an answer or update this one. (Other possibilities include through a 3rd party eg Twitter, Reddit.)

[image: Maintenance Alert Notification]

Comment: When there is a problem with the Battle.net service itself and you are unable to get into the launcher, the same message is shown on the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

As ChaseC mentionned, there is here and there some Forum "blue" (Blizzard employe) Posts that you can visit to see the service statut of a specific game easely accessible with the lest google skills. Although, you can directly go on your Battle.net desktop application if you have it. There you can see if each of the games or available for play.

If the servers are up but you can't access the games the problem is on your side. Check if something has changed in your network. I don't know your situation and then who has the administration on your router. But contact him/her and ask if something changed. (port forwarding and firewall.. I'm not really aware of those stuff but the chances are he/she will and letting him/her know won't make things worst hey?!

Finnaly, If you have installation or run-time problem or errors, Blizzard actualy provide a very good customer support on their websites. Go give it a try if you feel the need! :P

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score -1):

Here is the link for you to check out the server status of diablo 3. :)

http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/5394512/

Comment: I'm interested in the log in battle.net service specifically, not the status of any of the game specific servers.

Comment: Okay, well please mention that you are interested in a log in your question. There is no on-going log of battle.net server status available.